# Linqpad with firebird

Tags: firebird, linqpad

i have some troubles getting Firebird to work with LinqPad.

i am using version 5.02.03, and here the steps i have done :

1) first i have copied these assemblied into linqpad installation folder :

- EntityFramework.dll
- EntityFramework.Firebird.dll
- FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
- EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

2) Add Connection and choose Entity framework DBContext

3) Select the assembly that contain my DAL

4) the DBContext is properly recognized

5) for the question How should Linqpad instantiate the DBContext i choose via    paramaters connection and give my app.config

6) the connection test passed and i have my entiies populated in the treeview

**but** when i try a query, i have an exception

> InvalidCastException4 
>   [A]System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection cannot be cast to  [B]System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFramewor...

or  something like, because i am translating from french ...

any idea on what going on please , or is there another option to connect firebird with linqpad please ?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't see the entire exception message first time .

the problem was in entityFramework.dll that i have copied before in the linqpad directory, so i delete it , and it worked !